# Access SQL Query Returning Wrong Value for Count Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a `SQL` query that get's the Customer's name plus a column of `c` which is the `Count` of how many rows that connect to Referrals with `Customers.[Customer ID] = Referrals.[Referred From]` and `Referrals.[Used Our Service] = True`

And a second column with of `c2` which is the `Count` of how many rows that connect to Referrals with `Customers.[Customer ID] = Referrals.[Referred From]` and `Referrals.[Valid Referral] = True`

This query works fine but returns the wrong number in the `c2` column. It returns 2 when it should be 1.

```
SELECT 
Customers.[Customer ID], Customers.[First Name], Customers.[Last Name], Count(r.[Valid Referral]) AS c, Count(rr.[Used Our Service]) AS c2
FROM (Customers 
INNER JOIN Referrals r ON Customers.[Customer ID] = r.[Referred From] AND (r.[Valid Referral])=True)
INNER JOIN Referrals rr ON Customers.[Customer ID] = rr.[Referred From] AND (rr.[Used Our Service])=True
WHERE (r.[Valid Referral])=True
GROUP BY Customers.[Customer ID], Customers.[First Name], Customers.[Last Name]
```

Customers Table:

[image]

Referrals Table:

[image]

Result Table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that instead of joining the same table twice you use `SUM` together with `Iif`, like this:

```
SELECT 
Customers.[Customer ID], 
Customers.[First Name], 
Customers.[Last Name], 
SUM(Iif(r.[Valid Referral] = True, 1, 0)) AS c, 
Sum(Iif(r.[Used Our Service] = True, 1, 0)) AS c2
FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN Referrals r ON Customers.[Customer ID] = r.[Referred From] 
WHERE (r.[Valid Referral])=True
GROUP BY Customers.[Customer ID], Customers.[First Name], Customers.[Last Name]
```